# MySQL while loop insert

Tags: mysql, do-while, insert-update

I am facing a very strange problem with while loop insert on MySQL

Here's the background information of my test:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  `token` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `val1` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`token`)
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(
    IN token VARCHAR(16),
    IN token1 VARCHAR(16),
    IN token2 VARCHAR(16),
    IN token3 VARCHAR(16),
    IN token4 VARCHAR(16),
    IN val1 VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE tokenUsed VARCHAR(16);
    DECLARE trial INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tmpTok VARCHAR(16);
    
    WHILE (tokenUsed IS NULL AND trial < 5)
    DO
        SET tmpTok = CASE trial WHEN 0 THEN token WHEN 1 THEN token1 WHEN 2 THEN token2 
            WHEN 3 THEN token3 WHEN 4 THEN token4 END;
        
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test_table WHERE token = tmpTok)
        THEN
            SET tokenUsed = tmpTok;
            INSERT INTO test_table (token) VALUES(tmpTok);
        END IF;
        
        SET trial = trial + 1;
    END WHILE;
    
    IF tokenUsed IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        UPDATE test_table SET val1 = val1 WHERE token = tokenUsed;
    END IF;
    
    SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE token = tokenUsed;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I would call the stored proc servral times like this

```
CALL sp_test ('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'happy');
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

1. feed 5 random token to the sp
2. insert the first token available (i.e. not exists in test_table)
3. update the rest of the record with the inserted token and return that record

**Here are the symptom**

1. 1st call to *sp_test*, no problem, sp returned *| test1 | happy |*
2. 2nd call to *sp_test*, no error but sp returned nothing; *test2* is inserted but *val1* is not updated i.e. *| test2 | NULL |*
3. 3rd call to *sp_test* crashed with

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'test2' for key 'PRIMARY'

The while loop did move to token *test2* and inserted it to test_table but went no further, update also failed after *test2*.
The stored proc is quite straight forward and I have no idea why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: XY-problem. Post the task itself. Also tell what is precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your SP there is a row

```
UPDATE test_table SET val1 = val1 WHERE token = tokenUsed;
```

Both `val1` in it are local variable defined in SP parameters. The same about `token`. Must be

```
UPDATE test_table SET test_table.val1 = val1 WHERE test_table.token = tokenUsed;
```

Also check your code for the same issue in another statements.

2. Investigate your SP flow, like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d31de2054cc4077ceb26d2cf2da588ab